# GameObject Disappears in Unity Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Everything was working fine until I entered prefab mode. Then the character in the scene is no longer available but I can see it in game mode when I play the game.

I am at the beginner level learning JohnLemon haunted project.

I have no idea what to do.

Your help is highly appreciated.

I created transitions in the animator control for idle and walking. And I expected the character to still be visible in scene.

Comment: You could add screenshots of your panels and hierarchy tree to make it more clear. Is the character in the correct Z position?